# R: Concat columns from data frame using wildcards

Tags: regex, r, vector, dataframe, concatenation

I got stuck with a specific question in R around concatenating columns of a data frame by using a wildcard. Perhaps I am searching wrongly. However I could not find a matching answer yet.

Here is my question:
I have a data frame df where each column represents a user (U1, U2, U3), e.g.:

```
> df <-data.frame(U1=1:3, U2=4:6, U3=7:9)
> df
>  U1 U2 U3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

I would like to concatenate the values from all users into a single vector as one would do using the c() function, e.g.:

```
> c(df$U1, df$U2, df$U3)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

However, my number of users is large and varies over time. So, I look for an  elegant dynamic way of concatenating the columns such as

```
> c(df$U*)
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I played around with grep and regular expressions but could not get it to work. For sure, I could use a for-loop and program my own cat function but I assume there is a better way. I just don't find it. Maybe I am just blind. Hope you can help.

Comment: you want to concatenate all columns or just some columns ? i.e. columns that start with U??

Comment: Maybe just unlist the data.  `unlist(df[grepl("^U", names(df))], use.names = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub_df <- df[, grep(pattern ='^U.*', names(df))]    

stack(df)$values
```

Hope this works for you. You could first subset some columns according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Coerce the data frame to a matrix first:

```
as.vector(as.matrix(df))
```

Use the bracket `[` to select columns whose names match a certain expression:

```
df[, grep("U.*", colnames(df)), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Well, that works for the simplest example, what if they also have vars `"V1", "cats"` etc in the `df`? - they need a way to select out all the `U(n)` columns

Comment: @krlmlr Thanks for the suggestion but as @thelatemail pointed out this does not work as my original file has columns `U(1)-U(x),V(1)-V(y), W(1)-W(z)` and I want to concat U(1) to U(x) into a vector a, V(1) to V(y) into a vector b, and so on.

Comment: @deepdive - you might also want to consider the `reshape` and `stack` functions and their cousins in the world of `dplyr` and `data.table`

Comment: @krlmlr This worked: `as.vector(as.matrix(df[, grep("U.*", colnames(df)), drop = FALSE]))`, i.e. I just combined what you suggested. Cheers!